# An array of TextView Variables are not getting identified

Tags: android, textview

I trying to create an array of variables of `textviews` as shown below, but eclipse underscores my `textview` variables stored in the array with red squiggle. I do not know why?

Java_code:

```
int [] viewsRefsIds = {R.id.reportLocNameValue, R.id.reportLocLatValue, R.id.reportLocLngValue, R.id.reportTimeValue,
                    R.id.reportDateValue, R.id.reportImgTitleValue, R.id.reportImgPathValue
            };
            TextView [] viewsVariables = {reportAlertDialogLocName, reportAlertDialogLocLat, reportAlertDialogLocLng, 
                    reportAlertDialogTime, reportAlertDialogDate, reportAlertDialogImgTitle, reportAlertDialogImgPath
            };
            TextView reportAlertDialogMSG = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogMessageID);              
            reportAlertDialogMSG.setText(REPORT_ALERT_DIALOG_MSG);

            for (int i=0; i<bundleVals.length; i++) {
                viewsVariables[i] = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(viewsRefsIds[i]);
            }
```

Comment: What did you try? I'll post an answer...

Comment: as shown in the for loop above, i want to retrieve textview variables from the array "viewsVariables" and assign value to the retrieved variable.is it clear or not enough yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this works ...

```
int[] viewsRefsIds = {R.id.text,...};
TextView[] viewsVariables = new TextView[viewsRefsIds.length];
for (int i=0; i<viewsRefsIds.length; i++) {
    viewsVariables[i] = (TextView)findViewById(viewsRefsIds[i]);
}
```

maybe a "clean" helps :)

Comment: i tried this as well, but eclipse does not recognize it. I do not know why?